# Is there an event similar to dataSelected for the filter panel in power bi reports?

Tags: javascript, powerbi, powerbi-embedded

I'm embedding reports into an angular app using power bi's javascript api, and it would be useful to be able to send information about the filter pane from the report to the app.

The objective is to select a filter from the filter pane and send to the app what's the category of the chosen filter and what value was selected (for example an user picks "Porto" from the City filter and the app is able to console.log the words "Porto was selected from City").

Is there any function from the javascript api that does this? If not then what's a good idea to implement this?

Answer (score 3):

When a filter is applied, the report will be rendered again and `rendered` event will be called:

> **rendered** - Called when a report is fully rendered. For example, if all visuals are rendered on loading report or after user interaction.

You can [handle this event](https://github.com/microsoft/PowerBI-JavaScript/wiki/Handling-Events) and get information about [report](https://github.com/microsoft/PowerBI-JavaScript/wiki/Filters#report-level-filters), [page](https://github.com/microsoft/PowerBI-JavaScript/wiki/Filters#page-level-filters) and [visual](https://github.com/microsoft/PowerBI-JavaScript/wiki/Filters#visual-level-filters) level filters applied.